# Monty Hall-Not Running

Tags: python

I'm not sure what seems to be the problem with my code, I need some help. When I try running my program, it says invalid syntax next to my first if, I thought I may be an indentation error but nothing is working.

Here is my code:

```
import random

def montyHall():
    car = random.randint(1,3)
    guess1 = random.randint(1,3)
    for i in range(1,3):
        if ((not(i == car) and not(i == guess1)):
            return i

    newGuess = not(i) and not(guess1)
    if (newGuess == car):
        stay = True
    elif (guess1 == car):
        switch = False
    return strategyOne

NUM_OF_TRIALS = 1000
stay = 0
switch = 0

for i in range(NUM_OF_TRIALS):
    if(montyHall()):
        stay += 1
    else:
        switch += 1
print("Staying wins", stay/NUM_OF_TRIALS, "% of the time")
print("Switching wins", switch/NUM_OF_TRIALS, "% of the time")
```

Comment: Count (and match) your parentheses. Also, you don't need parentheses in [Python](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/controlflow.html) as you do in e.g. C.

Comment: This isn't directly related to your problem, but: what is `strategyone`? You return it at the end of the function, but that's the only place in the program that it appears.

Comment: Also: `not (i == car)` is better written as `i != car`. So write `if i != car and i != guess1:`.

Comment: @kevin i just wasn't sure what to put there. I'm very knew to programming so i'm kinda just winging it

Comment: Please fix your code formatting and indentation. This is vital in Python, and we can't fix your code if it's not represented accurately here.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker When I post it it looks messed up so I press the spacebar 4 times and it looks like it fits, I apologize it looks correct in my point of view but i will try to fix it

Comment: @NicoleArnone You can select the code and press the `{}` button in the toolbar (or Ctrl+K) to add 4 spaces everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To many brackets and you do not need brackets in python.

Try changing:

```
if ((not(i == car) and not(i == guess1)):
```

to

```
   if i != car and i != guess1:
```

Comment: Removing parentheses (not [brackets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket)) helps even more.

Comment: It does but I did not want to get into the semantics of his code and just answer the question.

Comment: @marsh I still get invalid syntax :/

Comment: @TimPietzcker It's not a problem, but it does help (and prevents sources of errors, like here).

Comment: @Evert Try reading the article you linked. e.g. "Brackets include parentheses, square brackets, curly brackets, angle brackets, and various other pairs of symbols"

Comment: Can someone please explain why I am getting so many downvotes?

Comment: @marsh It would help if you quote the incorrect line from the OP's code, to show the mistake. The previous version of your answer made it look like you're correcting an already correct line.

Comment: @interjay I guess it's what one's used to. The wiki article also says "In modern American usage this is usually the square bracket and in modern British usage this is usually the parenthesis.". I'm probably used to the American style, at least as far as programming is concerned.

Comment: Ah, thank you. It would help if you pointed out peoples mistakes in the future so that they may learn from them.

Comment: @TimPietzcker The original has unbalanced parentheses. One `(` with no matching `)`.